# Determine date and time from obscure hex encoding scheme

Tags: timestamp, hex, bit-manipulation, reverse-engineering, file-format

Thanks to ndkrempel the date portion of the hex has been deciphered. The time still remains to be decoded. However, with ndkrempel's work on the subject I've realized the entire time stamp includes an additional 7 bytes which I had previously ignored since my files normally contain timestamps with zero minutes or seconds. Here are some "complete" hex sequences that hopefully contain the remaining time data necessary for an accurate conversion:

```
C00AE440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712000000 = 17.05.1208.00.001024
C00AE440ABAAAAAAAAAAE23F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200E0C4 = 17.05.1214.00.001024
C00AE440610BB6600BB6E23F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF7120058C5 = 17.05.1214.02.001024
C00AE440176CC1166CC1E23F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200D0C5 = 17.05.1214.04.001024
C00AE440CDCCCCCCCCCCE23F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF7120048C6 = 17.05.1214.06.001024
```

---

Additional hex codes with various times

```
C00AE440721CC7711CC7E93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200E00F01 = 17.05.1219.20.001024
C00AE440CDCCCCCCCCCCE93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712001C1001 = 17.05.1219.21.001024
C00AE440287DD2277DD2E93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200581001 = 17.05.1219.22.001024
C00AE440DEDDDDDDDDDDE93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200D01001 = 17.05.1219.24.001024
C00AE440398EE3388EE3E93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712000C1101 = 17.05.1219.25.001024
C00AE440943EE9933EE9E93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200481101 = 17.05.1219.26.001024
C00AE440EFEEEEEEEEEEE93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200841101 = 17.05.1219.27.001024
C00AE4404A9FF4499FF4E93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200C01101 = 17.05.1219.28.001024
C00AE440A54FFAA44FFAE93F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200FC1101 = 17.05.1219.29.001024
C00AE440000000000000EA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200381201 = 17.05.1219.30.001024


E00AE4404A9FF4499FF4EA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712004C1C01 = 18.05.1220.13.001024
E00AE440D8822DD8822DEB3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200A41E01 = 18.05.1220.23.001024
E00AE440666666666666EB3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200FC2001 = 18.05.1220.33.001024
E00AE440F5499FF4499FEB3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200542301 = 18.05.1220.43.001024
E00AE440832DD8822DD8EB3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200AC2501 = 18.05.1220.53.001024
E00AE440111111111111EC3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200042801 = 18.05.1221.03.001024
E00AE4409FF4499FF449EC3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712005C2A01 = 18.05.1221.13.001024
E00AE4402ED8822DD882EC3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200B42C01 = 18.05.1221.23.001024
E00AE440BCBBBBBBBBBBEC3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF712000C2F01 = 18.05.1221.33.001024
E00AE440176CC1166CC1EC3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200482F01 = 18.05.1221.34.001024


E00AE440E42DCDC10BABDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200A28C00 = 18.05.1210.00.021024
E00AE4401DB1EFD86CABDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200A48C00 = 18.05.1210.00.041024
E00AE440563412F0CDABDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200A68C00 = 18.05.1210.00.061024
E00AE44090B734072FACDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200A88C00 = 18.05.1210.00.081024
E00AE440C93A571E90ACDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200AA8C00 = 18.05.1210.00.101024
E00AE44002BE7935F1ACDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200AC8C00 = 18.05.1210.00.121024
E00AE4403C419C4C52ADDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200AE8C00 = 18.05.1210.00.141024
E00AE44075C4BE63B3ADDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200B08C00 = 18.05.1210.00.161024
E00AE440AE47E17A14AEDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200B28C00 = 18.05.1210.00.181024
E00AE440E7CA039275AEDA3F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA3F0CF71200B48C00 = 18.05.1210.00.201024
```

---

**Preface: I checked to the best of my ability and the hex I am dealing with does not seem to conform to the "standard" hex date/time formats (time_t, time_64, DATE, DOS date/time as calculated by Hex Workshop as well as all the formats checked by the [DCode](http://www.digital-detective.co.uk/freetools/decode.asp) time decoder application).**

I am attempting to write a batch conversation utility to deal with a propriety file format generated by an in-house undocumented piece of software. I have the ability to convert the files with a long forgotten and similarly poorly documented utility, but it is a time intensive and tedious process which I would like to automate.

Simply using a hex editor I've been able to find everything I need except for how the date and time is encoded in the original files. I'm confident that I've identified the 27 byte hex sequence that represents the data I'm after as I can edit it to change the date and insert it into another file to transfer the date. However, I want to understand how it is actually generated so I can covert files with unknown dates.

Below is a sample of the hex sequences (left) and the time stamps they result in the converted file (right in the format: DD.MM.YYHH.MM.SS). Some are taken directly from files generated by the software, others are sequences I've manually edited to see how the date is changed. Anything with a year >12 was the result of my modifying the hex. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am not much of a programmer and am over my head here.

```
80D8E340ABAAAAAAAAAAEE3F555555555555DD3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 11.04.1123.00.001024

E008E440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 02.05.1208.00.001024

E001E440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 07.03.1208.00.001024

600AE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 14.05.1209.00.001024

610AE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 14.05.1209.00.001024

6001E440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 03.03.1209.00.001024

0101E440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 29.02.1208.00.001024

01010140555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 01.01.0008.00.001024

01010101555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 30.12.9908.00.001024

600AE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 14.05.1209.00.001024

60FFE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 25.09.1709.00.001024

60FFE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 25.09.1709.00.001024

60FFE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABFFFFFFFFFFEA = 25.09.1709.00.001024

60FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 25.09.1709.00.001024

01FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 22.09.1709.00.001024

02FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 22.09.1709.00.001024

10FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 22.09.1709.00.001024

20FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 23.09.1709.00.001024

30FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 23.09.1709.00.001024

40FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 24.09.1709.00.001024

50FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 24.09.1709.00.001024

60FFE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 25.09.1709.00.001024

600AE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 14.05.1209.00.001024

60FAE440000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 16.08.1709.00.001024

60FAE540000000000000D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 26.03.2309.00.001024

60FFE440FFFFFFFFFFFFD83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 25.09.1709.22.301024

60FFE440010101010101D83FAB0000000000DA3FAB0000000000EA = 25.09.1709.00.051024

40DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 27.05.1117.00.001024

60DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 28.05.1117.00.001024

800AE440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 15.05.1208.00.001024
```

Also, I should mention that the last 14 bytes do not seem particularly vital (although they do change in the original files). For example, the following sequences result in the same output after conversion. I don't know if those values are being rounded or simply stripped out during the conversion. Regardless, that part is not important if I can determine the month, day, year, hour, minute and second.

```
E008E440555555555555D53F555555555555FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 02.05.1208.00.001024

E008E440555555555555D53FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 02.05.1208.00.001024

E008E440555555555555D53F000000000000000000000000000000 = 02.05.1208.00.001024
```

The following were generated solely from the source software and have not been manually modified.

```
40DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 27.05.1117.00.001024

60DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 28.05.1117.00.001024

80D8E340ABAAAAAAAAAAEE3F555555555555DD3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 11.04.1123.00.001024

E008E440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 02.05.1208.00.001024

600AE440000000000000D83FABAAAAAAAAAADA3FABAAAAAAAAAAEE = 14.05.1209.00.001024

800AE440555555555555D53F555555555555D53FABAAAAAAAAAAEA = 15.05.1209.00.001024
```

The following are unmodified hex sequences from files with various times:

```
A0B7E340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 22.07.1016.00.001024

C0B7E340777777777777E73FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 23.07.1017.36.001024

A0EFE340CDCCCCCCCCCCE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 13.10.1117.06.001024

80EFE340BCBBBBBBBBBBE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 12.10.1117.03.001024

C0EEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE13FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 06.10.1113.15.001024

60D5E340ABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 17.03.1105.00.001024
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the format of the human-readable timestamp?  DD.MM.YYHH.MM.SSssss?

Comment: Have you taken one of these hex codes and systematically altered it?  For example, take the very first one and change the leading `8` to a `9` and how does the timestamp change?  Then again, start with the first one and change the 2nd digit from a `0` to a `1` and see what happens, etc.

Comment: DD.MM.YYHH.MM.SSssss, you say? And I hypothesised it was DD.MM.YYYY.00.HHMMSS! It goes to show what trouble **not** adhering to a standard causes. [Please always use ISO8601 for dates and times](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html)!

Comment: Having to decode one mystery date format is hard enough - why do you make us try to decode two? PLEASE understand that it's not obvious what the right side represents and tell us what it is!

Comment: @QuantumMechanic yes, you are correct on the timestamp. Also, I did attempt to systematically alter the date. For example only modifying the first byte (several are included above).

Comment: @MarkRansom Edited my question to include the date format.

Comment: The other thing we need to know is which numbers are straight from the program, and which ones are edited. You really need to be systematic about this.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the times are always even hours?  Can you give us a rough idea of what the function of these files are?  Bookkeeping program?  Numerical control program?  What?

Comment: @HotLicks The program that generated these files runs at a scheduled time (usually to coincide with some other external event) so is nearly always set to run on the hour for simplicity's sake. Thus the date/time I am trying to determine indicates when the program was set to start and serves as a reference point for all the other data in the file which is recorded continuously over multiple days. The one example I gave where it the time is 9:22:30 resulted from manually modifying the hex code. The program itself records amplified electrical signals (like EEG of sorts) and other sensor inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made some progress decoding the date/time format. Specifically, I can read the date, but I haven't tried reading the time yet.

I believe the format contains lots of extraneous, possibly garbage, data; and only a few of the bytes have significance.

The date is encoded in bytes 0, 1, and 2 only (the first 3 bytes).

It's easiest to explain by interpreting the first 4 bytes as a little-endian double-word (4 byte) quantity x. Then the day number, as an offset from 1989-09-17, is given by

d = (x & 0x000FFFFF) >> 5

I.e. you only look at the 20 lower order bits, and out of those you ignore the 5 lowest order bits. You could summarise this by saying that the day number is encoded in bits 5-19 inclusive (in particular, it is a 15-bit quantity).

Probably the time is encoded similarly in a different position of the data, but there aren't as many examples of different times, and I need to sleep also!

---

Ok, many of the preexisting data you give (not the ones you've manually generated), seem to have tampered time values (conceivably the result of local time zone conversions by one of the involved programs). But just by going on the ones you generated, it seems the time is encoded as follows:

Take bytes 9 and 10 (by which I mean the 10th and 11th bytes), and treat them as a little-endian word x. Mask out the top 2 bits, leaving a 14-bit quantity:

t = x & 0x3FFF

This represents the time of day. It is in units such that 0 corresponds to 00:00:00 and (one past) the maximum value, 16384, corresponds to 24:00:00. This gives it a resolution of about 5.3s.

In other words,

s = t / 16384. * 24. * 60. * 60.

gives the time as a number of seconds past midnight.

---

Ok, looking at the extra bytes you've now provided, bytes 32 and 33 (the last 2 bytes) seem to be an alternative time stamp. Treating it as a little-endian word x again, it directly encodes the number of seconds from midnight. When it is 0, it seems the time stamp described above is used instead. It seems it can only describe times up to 18:22 before overflowing, so it might also use an extra bit from the byte before? There isn't enough data to say any more.

---

Byte 34 is a continuation of the above. I.e. take bytes 32, 33 and 34 as a little-endian 3-byte quantity, then, at least when it's non-zero, it gives the number of seconds from midnight as above.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking that the data looks like something that you'd get from an LSSI shift register -- used to test computers.  Basically, the computer's clock is stopped and then all the data is shifted out of the registers as a serial stream.  Lots of meaningless data (unless you're testing the internals of stuff), and the significant bits will be scattered randomly among the rest (not necessarily in order).  In this case the 555... and AAA... patterns are probably left over bits in registers used to do decimal arithmetic.

Comment: I cannot even imagine how you figured that out. I updated my question with additional hex sequences corresponding to examples of various hours. Unfortunately examples with non-zero minutes are extremely rare.

Comment: @subcortical: There's something a bit strange going on with the times. Could you check these two again:
60DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6
A0B7E340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6
They're identical apart from the date information (the first 3 bytes), yet their times differ by 1 hour. I don't think this is a DST issue, as they should both lie in the DST period.

Comment: Oops, make that [LSSD](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=532648&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel3%2F3846%2F11214%2F00532648.pdf%3Farnumber%3D532648), not LSSI.  It's been a few years...

Comment: @nkdrempel My only explanation is that apparently in the past someone has tried to manually edit some of the output files to change the dates. I can confirm that if I convert files with the following sequences the time is the same. A0B7E340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 22.07.1017.00.001024

60DEE340ABAAAAAAAAAAE63FABAAAAAAAAAACA3FABAAAAAAAAAAE6 = 28.05.1117.00.001024

Comment: @subcortical: Ok, taking into account the dodgy time data, I've found the time format now - included in edit of answer above.

Comment: @ndkrempel Thanks for your work on this, however I am unable to consistently perform the time conversion using your instructions. I am sure you are correct, however, could you explain further as I am obviously doing something wrong

Comment: @ndkrempel For example, using the very first hex sequence posted in my question above, the 10th and 11th bytes are 0xAAEE and equal 61098, t = 0x2EAA (11946) and, s = 62996.48438 which works out to ~17.5 hours after midnight, not 23 as it should. Strangely I can make it work for others. For example, the 10th and 11th bytes in the second one is 0x55D5 (54613), t = 0x1555 (5461) s = 28798.24219 which is correctly 8 hours after midnight

Comment: @subcortical: Yes, you are performing all the calculations correctly. The first example simply doesn't match - it is one of the odd exceptions I alluded to. It is out by exactly 5.5 hours, so I think it could be a result of running the program in a different time zone. Have you tried feeding that data through the program yourself to see if it gives 23:00 or 17:30?

Comment: @ndkrempel Yes, converting a file with that entire hex sequence results in 23:00. If perhaps helpful: I altered a file with an 8:00 time (0x55D5) and replaced those 2 bytes with that from the 23:00 time (0x2EAA) and ended up with 01:15:44 which suggests to me that those 2 bytes alone do not contain the time. This is in contrast to the first 4 bytes which do seem to solely determine the date.

Comment: @ndkrempel See my update to the question. I believe I found the missing time data.

Comment: @subcortical: The new bytes you've provided seem to be quite simple, description included above. There are still some questions remaining, but I was unable to resolve them from the data you've given.

Comment: @ndkrempel I've updated the question with additional hexcodes for various numbers of minutes and seconds. I am currently generating examples with various hours but because I cannot manipulate the system clock it will take ~10 hours. I will update the question again with those sequences when I can. If a specific set of times would be useful, I can generate those as well.

Comment: @subcortical: Ok, got around to looking at the new data you provided - I notice you give an extra byte. That is simply a further byte of the time stamp described at the end of my answer. Updated above.